# Split a sentence using nltk and python

Tags: computational-linguistics, parsing, sentences, complex-sentences

I am working on a task which involves information extraction, for which I require splitting a complex sentence into a bunch of simple sentences. For instance,

> In optics a ray is an idealized model of light, obtained by choosing a
>   line that is perpendicular to the wavefronts of the actual light, and
>   that points in the direction of energy flow.

may be split as

> - ray is an idealized model of light.
> - ray is obtained by choosing a line that is perpendicular to wavefronts of actual light.
> - ray points in the direction of energy flow.

The only condition being, each simple form must in SVO (Subject-Verb-Object) format. For example for sentence `ray is an idealized model of light`

```
Subject - ray
Verb - is
Object - idealized model of light
```

What approach should I take? I am using NLTK and python 2.7. Can [dependency parsing](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp#sample) be of any help?

Comment: If you need only English, I would use spacy.io for this, it is much more lightweight and better than NLTK.  eg displacy.spacy.io?share=2355455701063440884

Comment: note: 'ray' is not a valid subject, but 'a ray' ('every ray') is.  Your 3rd split is ambiguous; it may only be the 'chosen line' that points in the direction of energy flow.  {It just happens that 'obtained' means 'equal to'}

Comment: Dependency parses will give you all the dependencies so yes, dependency parsing would help you extract all the subtrees you're interested in.

Comment: It's not possible. In "A ray is [an idealised model of flight]", the bracketed element is a predicative complement, not an object.

Answer (score 3):

If you are familiar with spacy, you can use the dependency of the words in the sentence:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("Apple is looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion")

for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.lemma_, token.pos_, token.tag_, token.dep_,
            token.shape_, token.is_alpha, token.is_stop)
```

`token.dep_` can give you the root ( verb) and the relations in the sentence.

DEPENDENCY EXAMPLE

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("This is a sentence.")
displacy.serve(doc, style="dep")
```

displacy helps visualizing the relations in the sentences.

You can check https://spacy.io/ for more information.